# Macbook Pro Retina 15", Mid 2012 - High Speed HDMI Cable

Tags: mac, hdmi, macbook-pro-retina, high-resolution

I got  a High Speed HDMI Cable with Ethernet that supports up to 4096 x 2160 pixels. I connected  my macbook pro retina 15" to a 27" monitor that supports a resolution of 2560 x 1440 via this cable, but the maximum resolution it's 1080p.

I am pretty sure that the video card supports this kind of resolution since it's NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB and HDMI Cable to.

I am a web - front end developer and I have a windows machine and I need to switch between the 2 for testing.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this thread...

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4021089?start=0&tstart=0

... the port supports HDMI 1.4 (higher than 1080p res) under Windows but OSX arbitrarily limits output to 1080p. Apparently you can get higher res from the DisplayPort (*cough* sorry ThunderBolt(TM)) interface so if that's an option (you don't mind buying an adapter) you could try that. If this isn't a driver limitation then it might be reserving the extra bandwidth for use as the ethernet channel but it could just be Apple being dicks (making HDMI look bad to favour their own DisplayPort/Thunderbolt proprietary interface and accessories).

EDIT: Little more [research](http://www.paradetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/PS8401-Product-Brief-20110425.pdf) shows the HDMI repeater chip supports HDMI 1.4 with 3.0Ghz bandwidth (which the spec sheet says is 4Kx2K capable) so it isn't a hardware restriction, it's definitely OSX or driver restriction (whether deliberate or accidental only Apple knows).

Comment: +1. I would add that a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort Adapter Cable can do the trick. I got one (1.8m) from Amazon for about 7 pounds.

Comment: @Radoo Yes, this works for me to. I guess the issue is with the monitor as well. Even if the mac would output high resolutions, the monitor treats HDMI as a video input for HD only.

Comment: What's the max res on the monitor with the Windows machine?